# Calendar upcoming releases laravel application

Tags: laravel, calendar, movies

I have an application in Laravel, this'm riding a calendar of upcoming releases of series and movies.

I need to show the upcoming releases, is already working the register, but they can help me make display according to earliest date?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us what you currently have ? The information you provided is not enough. Are you currently using some plugins for the calendar ? What's your DB Schema ? What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Depending if the Upcoming releases are Eloquent models, then you can do something like :

```
UpcomingReleases::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
```

Keep in mind that "UpcomingReleases" is a name i just came up with, until i know for sure what models are you using